# How to get the top compound search terms using elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to get the top searched terms from elasticsearch. We are using the significant terms functionality provided by elasticsearch but this feature is only able to get top single word search terms. Instead, we need to the top multi-word searches.

Is there currently a way of doing this within elasticsearch?

The following is a relevant query we are using:

```
GET /mentions/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "snippet": {
                "query": "#Hashtag"
            }
        }
    },
   "aggs": {
        "trends": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "snippet",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing how your data looks likes? specifically how does an "average" snippet field look like? is it capped by a certain amount of words?

Comment: @tomslabbaert It contains text from tweets or content from news articles. Example: 
In love with site. \nWhether you like cricket or not, please support the role it is playing in conveying a peace mes…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common phrase problem has no "magic" solution,

However the best approach to dealing with this problem, i feel is using the [N-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) concept.

Basically instead of indexing your text for single words (as the top terms aggregation search is limited on indexed terms only) either create a new analyzer thats tailored for you if you have a specific idea on how to do it or create one using [Common gram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-common-grams-tokenfilter.html) which i feel could work great for you as elasticsearch devs are smart (presumably) and their solution is probably more efficient than what you or i would craft up hastley.

Just note, i'm not sure whats your scale but this solution will use a-lot more disk space and might affect other queries efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom's response in that there's no solution that works for all use cases. Elasticsearch has no concept of how to sort searched terms in order to provide you with a list of the top ones.

For example, if you're storing Tweets in your Elasticsearch instance, are top search terms the ones with the most likes? The most retweets? Do you use a combination of those two metrics and how recently the tweet was made? That's really dependent on your use case.

You could get top search terms by frequency but then maybe you're including words like 'and' or 'the' that aren't very useful. To guard against this, you would have to consider removing stop words upon storage of search phrases and not just on retrieval (see: [elasticsearch stopwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stopwords.html)). Elasticsearch provides a set of language analyzers out of the box improving search performance on a corpus of documents (see: [using elasticsearch language analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-language-analyzers.html)).